ReferenceError: Cannot access 'ProductCategory' before initialization in sequelize-typescript with Nestjs
I am trying to use Sequelize + Postgres with Nestjs, and I've defined few Models in different resources, and having HasMany, HasOne relationships with BelongsTo() in the ForeignKey Table, but I am getting below error:
export class ProductDetailsModel extends Model {
             ^


ReferenceError: Cannot access 'ProductDetailsModel' before initialization
    at ProductDetailsModel (C:\Users\dhaval\Desktop\Coursera Learning\Free_Projects\fabric-fusion\server\src\admin\products\models\product.model.ts:13:14)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\dhaval\Desktop\Coursera Learning\Free_Projects\fabric-fusion\server\src\admin\products\models\return-policy.model.ts:24:39)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1469:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1548:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1288:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1104:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1311:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:179:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\dhaval\Desktop\Coursera Learning\Free_Projects\fabric-fusion\server\src\admin\products\models\product.model.ts:5:29)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1469:14)

Node.js v20.17.0

even I tried this way -> https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize-typescript?tab=readme-ov-file#one-to-many
where below is my ProductCategory Model:
import { AutoIncrement, Column, DataType, HasMany, Model, Table } from "sequelize-typescript";

// Product Sub Category Model
import { ProductSubCategory } from "src/admin/sub-category/models/sub-category.model";

@Table({ tableName: "productCategory" })
export class ProductCategory extends Model {
  @AutoIncrement
  @Column({ type: DataType.UUIDV4, primaryKey: true, allowNull: false })
  productCategoryId: string;

  @Column({ type: DataType.STRING, allowNull: false, unique: true })
  productCategoryName: string;

  @HasMany(() => ProductSubCategory)
  productSubCategoryFk: ProductSubCategory[];

  @Column({ defaultValue: false, type: DataType.BOOLEAN })
  isDeleted: boolean;
}

and below is ProductSubCategory Model:
import { AutoIncrement, BelongsTo, Column, DataType, ForeignKey, Model, Table } from "sequelize-typescript";

// Category Model
import { ProductCategory } from "src/admin/category/models/category.model";

@Table({ tableName: "productSubCategory" })
export class ProductSubCategory extends Model {
  @AutoIncrement
  @Column({ type: DataType.UUIDV4, primaryKey: true, allowNull: false })
  productSubCategoryId: string;

  @Column({ type: DataType.STRING, allowNull: false, unique: true })
  productSubCategoryName: string;

  @Column({ type: DataType.STRING, allowNull: false })
  productSubCategoryImage: string;

  @ForeignKey(() => ProductCategory)
  @Column
  productCategoryFk: string;

  @BelongsTo(() => ProductCategory)
  productCategory: ProductCategory;

  @Column({ defaultValue: false, type: DataType.BOOLEAN })
  isDeleted: boolean;
}

both are in different resources, and having relationship this way, but I am getting same error:
ReferenceError: Cannot access 'ProductCategory' before initialization
@Module({
  imports: [
    // for .env
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      isGlobal: true,
      envFilePath: [".env.development", ".env.test", ".env.production"],
    }),

    // for DB Connection
    SequelizeModule.forRoot({
      dialect: process.env.DB_TYPE as "postgres",
      host: process.env.DB_HOST,
      port: Number(process.env.DB_PORT),
      username: process.env.DB_USERNAME,
      password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
      database: process.env.DB_DATABASE_NAME,
      autoLoadModels: true,
      synchronize: true,
      logging: true,
      timezone: "+05:30",
      repositoryMode: true,
      sync: { alter: true },
    }),

    // RateLimiter
    // no more than 3 calls in a second, 20 calls in 10 seconds, and 100 calls in a minute.
    ThrottlerModule.forRoot([
      {
        name: "short",
        ttl: 1000,
        limit: 3,
      },
      {
        name: "medium",
        ttl: 10000,
        limit: 20,
      },
      {
        name: "long",
        ttl: 60000,
        limit: 100,
      },
    ]),

    // Admin Modules
    AdminAuthModule,
    // AdminProductsModule,
    AdminProductCategoryModule,
    AdminProductSubCategoryModule,
    // AdminProductSizeModule,
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_GUARD,
      useClass: AuthGuard,
    },
    AppService,
  ],
})
export class AppModule implements NestModule {
  configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
    consumer.apply(AuthMiddleware).forRoutes(
      AppController,
      // AdminProductsController,
      AdminProductCategoryController,
      AdminProductSubCategoryController,
    );
  }
}

this is my app.module.ts file
I am not able to find what's the issue and how to fix it, even I tried to add models: [], but I'm still encountering the same issue: ReferenceError: Cannot access 'ProductCategory' before initialization
